# Making an autosort macro for an excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

this is the code i have, i open the document and can  make one change and then it freezes, it is also not sorting correctly,

i am testing this as i have a workbook with a sheet that has over 100 sort aria's that i want to use this on

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error Resume Next
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b:b")) Is Nothing Then
            Range("a1:b13").Sort Key1:=Range("b2"), _
            Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely stuck in an error loop and you have blanket told the code to continue on error. Remove `On Error Resume Next` and it will crash when you run it and tell you the issue.

Comment: The calculate event has no `Target` parameter.

Comment: Every time something gets updated on your worksheet the worksheet_Calculate function will be called. If you have a macro that runs when the calculate function gets called and that macro then changes something it will call the calculate function and thus your macro again. Possibly quickly ending up spiraling in to a crash. So the enable events should be false whilst you run your macro. The other two comments above mine are also valid.

Comment: That last line of `Application.EnableEvents = False` would turn off events the first time your code was triggered, and the event would not get called again after that.

Comment: @dan Donoghue i have removed On Error Resume Next now i get runtime error 424 object required

Comment: This will be because as @Tim Williams noticed, there is no Target on the calculate event. I would probably change your event to `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` at the sheet level not the book level for what it looks like you are trying to do. Note: If this fixes things mark @ed2 below as the accepted response as he posted it before I did.

Comment: as i am extremely new to this and still not working, if i change to Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) then when my formula's update they do not sort ,

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to do to get this working. They are listed here in order of importance, but you should do them all.

1. Choose a different event

---

Consider which event you want to hook. Hooking Worksheet_Calculate is problematic if you are providing something that it needs to then recalculate again - it will just get stuck forever. Perhaps try hooking a different event instead, such as:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

2. Use error trapping to your advantage

---

You have `On Error Resume Next` which should be removed or commented out while you are troubleshooting, so that it can break on the error and tell you what is going wrong.

3. Update syntax to match the event

---

The variable `Target` above is not working as intended, as it does not relate to the chosen event Worksheet_Calculate. This will be fixed along the way when looking at #1 above.

You can find more info about this event at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-macro-cells-change